# how to auto precompile asset when client upload images in production in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5

My rails' app has uploading images function.

Precompiled assets will be created in public/assets When I deploy rails app in production and run

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

I will get below error messages every time user upload images successfully in admin platform and request showing that created image.
    ActionView::Template::Error (The asset `"course/main_photo/XXXX/Course_ss12344.png"` is not present in the asset pipeline.):

In those messages, I found that images created by user didn't precompile in the public/assets.

```
config.assets.compile = true # when I set true for config.assets.compile, server will response assets slowly that is not good choice.

config/environments/production.rb  # below is my relative code in production's config
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how to auto precompile assets or other advice when user upload images online?

Comment: Is `course/main_photo/XXXX/Course_ss12344.png` an image you expect to exist? Or being uploaded by a user? How is the image link from the view?

Comment: `course/main_photo/XXXX/Course_ss12344.png` <-- that is user created. I created course admin page for user to upload their course and relative images. The path of image uploading will created in `app/assets/images/course/main_photo/model_id/xxx.png`. Yes, image link is from view.

Comment: That means you have a hardcoded link in a view to an image that must be uploaded from a user and may not exists? And you store those user uploads in the assets folder on the server?

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for replying. I use html image tag(<img>) and set src to `image_path(course/main_photo/xxxx/xxx.png)`. I can sure that these images uploaded by user exist in `app/assets/images/course/xxxx/`. 

I am wondering that `assets.compile` setting to false alwayse search for `public/assets/course/main_photo/xxxx/encoded_name.png`. Means that the new created images by user in production must run again rake assets command to rebuild that images in `public/assets/....`. How the people do automatically(run by rails or doing some tricky way ) precompile assets.

Comment: I wonder why you took this uncommon approach? Usually – IMHO all – articles about this topic suggest that files uploaded by a user are stored external or in the `public/system` folder. And more importable that user uploads do not get delivered via the asset pipeline. This approach fights against common Rails conventions (see the Rails Guide about user uploads) and is error-prone (What if that file does not exist? What if you want to use an environment like Heroku or multiple servers?). This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for replying. I am newbie to Rails, only know to preview images in a view is via asset pipeline. 
I thought that image showing in views must via assets pipeline. I used to put images uploaded by user in other path(e.g., `upload/course/`) and rails alwayse get delivered image via assets pipeline. I have google for Rails Guide about user uploads and get active storage articles which is a good way to do that for Rails 5.2+. Can you give me some links about relative articles or some key words to study? Is there another approach to get image in view not via assets pipeline.

Comment: Exactly, [Active Storage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) is is the recommended way when you are using current Rails versions.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks you for helping me. Active Storage is works for my app. I have another question about what people use kind of ways to do get image not via assets pipeline under Rails 5.2.

Comment: Paperclip or carrierwave are two other gems for file uploading

Comment: Yes I used to carrierwave to upload images but my questions is how to bypass asset pipeline when requesting images to preview in a view.

Comment: Simply by not using the asset pipeline helper methods like `image_path`. But instead using the methods that are provided by the gem or by storing the images at a place to with you can link without that helper methods – in the `public` folder or in an external location like S3.

Comment: Very thanks you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Remove previous pre-compiled assets by running 
"rake assets:clobber"
than do "rake assets:precompile" and Restart your server

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't want manually run rake command in command line because I can't always get exception then manually running those rake command to rebuild assets in public/assets every time user upload their images. I hope that precompile assets can automatically run by system.